# Understanding Spin, (from Griffiths), a Paradox?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

In Griffiths', *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 3rd ed*, Sec. 4.4.1 **Spin 1/2** the author represents the spin state by a spinor
$$
\chi = \binom{a}{b} = a\chi_+ + b\chi_-, \qquad \chi_+ = \binom{1}{0},\quad \chi_- = \binom{0}{1},\quad |a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1
$$
where the latter two represent the spin up and the spin down along the $z$-axis, i.e., they are the eigenspinors of the $S_z$ for the eigenvalues $+\hbar/2$ and $-\hbar/2$, respectively. After he constructs the **Pauli spin matrices** he finds the eigenspinors of the $S_x$ to be
$$
\chi_+^{(x)} = \binom{1/\sqrt{2}}{1/\sqrt{2}},\quad \chi_-^{(x)} = \binom{1/\sqrt{2}}{-1/\sqrt{2}}
$$
for the eigenvalues $+\hbar/2$ and $-\hbar/2$, respectively. And therewith
$$
\chi = \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}\ \chi_+^{(x)} + \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}\ \chi_-^{(x)} \tag{*}
$$

**Question:** If I choose $a = \cos \theta, b = \sin \theta$ then $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ is fullfiled. But in the case $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ (which means equal probabilities for $\chi_+$ and $\chi_-$) we get from ($*$) that $\chi = \chi_+^{(x)}$ which is a determinate (certain) state of $S_x$, and it means spin up along the $x$-axis, i.e., in the positive direction. But how does it know which is the positive direction ? why isn't it the other direction, since we could choose the opposite direction along $x$ as the positive ?

Stated another way: If the particle is in a state such that it is equally likely to get by measurement $+\hbar/2$ or $-\hbar/2$ along some axis ($z$-axis, say), How does measuring the spin at this state along *some* perpendicular *line* gives  the positive direction along that line, though one may have not yet chosen which direction is the positive and which is the negative ?

Comment: Indeed, $(\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)\mapsto  (-\sigma_x, -\sigma_y, \sigma_x)$ is an isomorphism of the su(2)/Pauli algebra.

Comment: You are free to do anything you wish, if you  chose to redefine/reflect directions in x and y simultaneously, keeping z invariant. This corresponds to rotating your system around z by just π. Changing conventions is not a paradox.

Comment: Ahhh yes, apology... the very last sigma is $\sigma_z$....

Comment: But sorry, I still don't understand, could you give an *explicit* answer, because physically it is not clear what happens, as if the *process* of measurement along a *line* implies also a *direction* aswell

Comment: I don't  see a question to answer. You do what you say and find the answer you did. Calling a direction positive or negative is a choice, albeit we all try to use uniform conventions.

Comment: @Physor If $\sigma_x$ is an observable, then so is $-\sigma_x$. Measuring one is completely equivalent to measuring the other, except that the outcomes are labeled differently. Is this statement consistent with how you're thinking about things, or is this in conflict with the way you're thinking about things? (I'm asking this because it might help identify the source of confusion.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly The source of confusion seems to be that the outcome of the measurement at the state $\theta =  \frac{\pi}{4}$ along the perpendicular line *decides* the positive direction. If I think about it physically it doesn't make sense at all

Answer (score 3):

I'm summing up, What @Cosmas Zachos said,

The first direction in space is unique but not it's representation. The one I'm calling positive $x$-axis, you can call $-x$-axis or vice-versa. We know that Spinors are generators of [SU(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(2)) group which correspond to rotation in $3D$ (naively) without changing right hand to left hand system.

For instance:

In our case :
$$\chi=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}\chi^x_++\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}\chi^x_-$$
Now apply a rotation of $\pi$ about $z$-axis so that

$$R(\pi\hat{z})=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi) & \sin(\pi)\\
-\sin(\pi) & \cos(\pi) 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0  \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$R(\pi\hat{z})\chi=-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}\chi^x_+-\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}\chi^x_-$$
If you work out the whole algebra for the case $a=b$ lead you to
$$\chi'=-\chi^x_-$$
That's the negative direction which is equivalent to other.

Answer (score 2):

> though one may have not yet chosen which direction is the positive and which is the negative ?

You did choose the direction when you chose the spinor basis. You have to prepare a system in the state $\binom{1/\sqrt{2}}{1/\sqrt{2}}$ before you do your measurement, and whatever method you use to do that will make use somehow of the fact that that state points in the +x direction in your basis. There's no way to create that state through measurements along the z axis, or a magnetic field directed along the z axis, or anything else that doesn't break the x/y symmetry.

The complex-vector representation of spin obscures the geometry. It's somewhat clearer to imagine a Pauli spinor as a quaternion representing a rotation from a canonical spinor orientation to the actual orientation. If you take the canonical spinor to be pointing in the +z direction, and $\binom10$ to represent the quaternion $1$, then $\binom01$ has to be a unit quaternion perpendicular to $1$, i.e. a pure imaginary quaternion. If you pick $j$ – i.e., a 180° rotation in the xz plane – then $\binom{1/\sqrt{2}}{1/\sqrt{2}}$ is $(1{+}j)/\sqrt2$, or a 90° rotation in the xz plane, and this leaves the spinor pointing in the +x direction (or -x; I wish there weren't so many sign conventions). The quaternionic representation makes it clearer that $\binom10$ and $\binom01$ aren't (can't be) just "+z" and "-z"; they have another spatial direction hidden in them.